# iFrame URL parameter to an in Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, iframe

I have a page which has an iframe embed of an external page. I want to find zip code

Here is my iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://mortgagerates.icanbuy.com/?zip=" width="1020" height="1200">
```

http://mortgagerates.icanbuy.com/?zip=10458 (Main Site )

But i want i frame and my browser url same below:

http://www.mysite.com/?zip=10458 (I want something like that)

Is this possible in wordpress? how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check it.. I hope work it...

```
<iframe src="http://mortgagerates.icanbuy.com/?zip" width="1020" height="1200"  class="iframe-wrapper">
```

And add this jQuery. Thats It!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
    var search = window.location.search;
    search = search.replace("?","&");

    $(".iframe-wrapper").attr("src", $(".iframe-wrapper").attr("src")+search);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is ajax page. you want to use ajax.

```
http://mortgagerates.icanbuy.com/ajax/rates-search?callback=jQuery17209362620610679678_1385958692723&source=1&results_count=0&period=PERIOD_FIXED_30YEARS&state=33&property_type=34&occupancy=49&fico=740&points=1.5&currently_working=Yes&property_interested=Yes&show_fha=0&cashout=0&city=10458&valoans=0&militaryaff=1&hadvabefore=0&rate_lock=99&loan=200000&transaction=54&ltv=80&cltv=80&DO_UPDATE_WRITE=0&id=d4ea9f8db0477778&external=0&_=1385958692873
```

you need to pass your `zipcode` into `city=10458`. its return json encoded format. you simply parse this into your design.